# python compare ip range to host file

Tags: python, ip, ip-address, subnet

I have a simple python script that compares a range using netaddr with the host file. I need to print the whole range and the matches. This as far as I can go. Snippet below:

```
ip_range = sys.argv[1]
host_file = open('/etc/hosts')
for ip in IPNetwork(ip_range).iter_hosts():
    ip_results.append('%s' % ip)

for Z in ip_results:
    for X in host_file:
        if Z in X:
            print Z, X
```

Something like this:

192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1 host1

192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 host2

192.168.1.3

I would like to still print the IP even if there is no match.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for Z in ip_results:
    for X in host_file:
        if Z in X:
            print Z, X else: print Z

Comment: With that added it will be printed twice as a result of the loop. With a file that has 

192.168.1.1 ['192.168.1.1', 'host1']
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.2 ['192.168.1.2', 'host2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution would be to initialize a match variable and then print the ip once if it doesn't turn on.  For example:

```
for Z in ip_results:
    matching = 0
    for X in host_file:
        if Z in X:
            print Z, X
            matching = 1
    if matching == 0:
        print Z
```

Comment: my pleasure!  first time I've been able to answer a python question, so I'm improving!  :-)

Comment: Keep going! Very much appreciated.